# 3d matrices in C++ using gsl_vector

Tags: c++, templates, matrix

I have written a lot of my code using the `gsl_vector` type from the GSL library. I have created a 3D matrix by simply using `vector< vector <gsl_vector * > >`. In fact, theoretically one can use any `vector` class in the inner template: `vector< vector < VEC > >`, one doesn't necessarily need a pointer, but I would like to avoid making this change for the present.

However, I would like to avoid using the `std::vector` class in order to avoid the additional overhead it causes, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20537195/do-i-have-a-memory-inconcistency-macos). Can anyone suggest a convenient way to do this?

NB: I need `gsl_vector` also to perform BLAS operations.

SUGGESTION: Use `vector<gsl_matrix*>` and vector views.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you chose not to take advantage of the GLM library?

Answer (score 0):

What about allocating a 2D array of pointers to `gsl_vector`s. See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/1768382/3146587 for an example.